# I am trying to build a monthly revenue prediction model using Prophet in Python but how can I optimize the hyperparameters of the model?

Tags: python, forecasting, optimization, hyperparameter, prophet

The hyperparameters which I am trying to optimize are: 'n_changepoints', 'changepoint_range', 'holidays_prior_scale', 'seasonality_prior_scale' and 'changepoint_prior_scale'. 'changepoint_range' has a range between 0.1 and 1, but all the other parameters don’t have any specific range, so that’s why there are thousands of combinations for the parameters which I can choose for my model. I am calculating the 'Mape' value after each iteration, and my aim is minimizing the 'Mape' value by finding the optimal hyperparameter values. I couldn't find any example regarding hyperparameter optimization for Prophet in Python, so it would be great if you can explain which optimization algorithm I should use on this model and how.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```py
prophet_df= hotels_prophet_df.rename(columns{'CheckOutDate':'ds','Revenue':'y'})
m = Prophet(growth='linear',
            n_changepoints=55.367067692472375,
            changepoint_range=0.5360234895566393,
            daily_seasonality=True,
            weekly_seasonality=True,
            yearly_seasonality=True,
            seasonality_mode='multiplicative',
            holidays_prior_scale=17.570880514919946,
            seasonality_prior_scale=32.46673193879147,
            changepoint_prior_scale=24.092991208181726)
m.fit(prophet_df)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=12, freq='M')
forecast = m.predict(future)
figure = m.plot(forecast, xlabel='CheckOutDate', ylabel='Revenue')
a = add_changepoints_to_plot(figure.gca(), m, forecast)
plt.show()
df_cv = cross_validation(m, initial='2100 days', period='180 days', horizon = '365 days')
df_p = performance_metrics(df_cv)
print('mape:', '{:.2f}%'.format(100 * df_p['mape'].mean()))
df_cv
```

Comment: why don't you post your data ...noting what country and the starting date  . you need to be searching for lead and lag effects around holidays, days of the week effects AND possible changes in those effects over time, day-of-the-month effects , week-of-the month effects. month-of-the-tear effects, level/step shifts in the data , local time trends in the data , arima structure in the data , required transformations to stabilize/homogenize the error variance, et al .

Comment: You can see the part of my data and the visualization above. Data starts from Jan-2013 and its the revenue data of the company which I work for in Turkey. For this project I am working on monthly data, I am not working on daily data so I don't think holiday dates would affect the model. You can also see the screenshot of the code I am using and the Mape value above.'yhat' values on the table are my prediction results. Can you give me some recommendations on how I can reduce 'Mape' value in this model and how can I implement an hyperparameter optimization algorithm on this model?

Comment: could not see your data. please post the actual NOT the picture ...

Comment: I have the data in the excel file but it is 84 rows how can I post it here? Do I have a chance to share the excel file?

Comment: You can give hyperopt a try http://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/